# Remix + Metamask not fetching any values

Tags: remix, metamask

I have a simple test contract that stores a hash and I deployed it via Remix and Metamask

```
pragma solidity 0.4.25;

contract Hash {
    bytes32 hash;

    constructor(bytes32 _hash) public {
        hash = _hash;
    }

    function getHash() public view returns (bytes32) {
        return hash;
    }
}
```

so far, so good. The contract can be found [here](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xce76ea74ad6ec12e571e5ddfe8e8366011c6fa14)

I passed "0xE6648B14C7E8303258E7DA8CC80540A6C56EC8D7118A6F88D39E836E31FFC2D0" in the constructor as a hash.

But when I call the getHash function I get the following result:

[image]

But when I change the provider to my local parity node I get the following correct result:

[image]

Why am I getting the wrong result with metamask?

Comment: Metamask, Parity node, and Javascript VM are all working for me. Are you confirming the transaction with Metamask and can you see it on Etherscan?

Comment: Yes I confirm the transactions with Metamask and the transactions go through without a problem. I just can't seem to read from the blockchain for some reason

Comment: nevermind.. contract calls run out of gas

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Metamask is having issues with Ropsten right now, that's why it's not working properly